# How does work scheduleOnce with a selector and params?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Xcode is expecting a ')' just before the YES

`[_creep scheduleOnce:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES) delay:2.0f];`

Sorry if it seems basic stuff... I just started ObjectiveC.

Comment: You don't pass arguments to a selector, they're passed when the selector gets invoked.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `removeFromParentAndCleanup`?

Comment: It's cocos2d stuff: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a0d4e615f688458c74001acf10f0ae011

Comment: Thx. It works but how do you pass params then if it is really needed?

Comment: I will add a method to the Creep class calling the same selector with params :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because the Cocos API limits you to one selector with 1 argument (ccTime), write your own method that passes the given arguments to the proper function:

```
-(void)doneWithSomething {
    [self scheduleOnce:@selector(removeAndCleanup:) delay:2.0f];
}

-(void)removeAndCleanup:(ccTime)delta {
    [ _creep removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

You cannot pass arguments in the `@selector()` directive because it directly correlates to an entry in either a vTable (for common methods) or an entry in the ObjC sel cache, so the compiler thinks you're trying to invoke an impossibly named method called `-removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES`